# Simple secure standalone "offline" app to generate securely random passwords

Tags: security

I'm looking for an app (used on laptop) to generate long, securely random, 1-use passwords that are impossible to be memorized.

It **must** be "offline" or at least openly verifiably sandboxed from a possibly malicious server.

The random seed **must** be cryptographically secure.

It's best if it allows an additional option for "variable user input" for modifying the random seed, eg via keyboard/mouse etc.

It's best if it's not from US/UK/Canada, but if so, it's best there is proper evidence that there is no FBI backdoor.

Comment: Would simply generating a hash from a random source of data work? On a *nix system - `dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=100 | md5sum` or similar ...

Comment: @ivanivan, That would be a great stopgap if it would work, but I'm on a Mac.

Comment: Mac? Open the Terminal.app thingie and it will work.  In fact, lemme get you a good answer typed in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, since you are on a Mac, you can take advantage of that under the hood Unix goodness.

All *nix systems provide `/dev/random`, or possibly `/dev/urandom` or `/dev/arandom`.  These provide random data base on noise generated by device drivers, OS function calls, all sorts of stuff to provide true randomness.

So, what you can do to generate random stuff suitable for password use is a little command line magic.  Open the Terminal.app thingie, and at the prompt something like

```
dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=100 | openssl sha -sha256
```

This should give you output like

```
$ dd if=/dev/random bs=1 count=100 | openssl sha -sha256
100+0 records in
100+0 records out
100 bytes copied, 0.000293454 s, 341 kB/s
(stdin)= f4a5f44ee7351ba4d1f2ca7a7722ae79c0cbbb5e3ab4e9b60ddcfa92368e6ff1
```

and that nice long string can be used as a password.

What is this doing?  It is grabbing 100 random bytes of data provided by `/dev/random` and instead of outputting to a file or the screen the output is piped to be the input for the `openssl` command.

Feel free to use more/less bytes of random data.  In fact, if just having a nice long random string works for your purposes you could get the SHA256 hash of files on your system, etc.

Comment: Nice, I'd take this as a stopgap until a better one comes along if any. initially I was thinking along the lines of something like a UI (javascript) page that takes optional mouse/key input. ¶ Btw, is there a cmd for "SHA256 of last modified file on the filesystem"?

Comment: @Pacerier sure, just a little more shell scripting magic, using `find`, `sort` and either `head` or `tail` (depending on sort order) - but it will be disk intensive and take time.  Not sure of what "notify" or "dialog" type utils there are on OS X, in Linux we have wrappers to provide a gui for shell scripts (`zenity`, etc).  Not sure if you'd be better asking at unix.stack or over on askdifferent ...